# Why does the following python code print 4 lines instead of 3?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
def beauty():
    print("Belle")
    return "Beast"

def gaston():
    if beauty() == "Beast":
        print("No one’s as slick")
    elif beauty() == None:
        print("No one’s as quick")
    if beauty() == "Belle":
        print("What a guy")
    else:
        print("Belle")  

gaston()
```

Can anyone please explain why the code above is printing 4 lines instead of 3?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain why you would expect it to print 3 lines?

Comment: I'd expect four. When you call beauty() in the 'if' test 'Belle' is printed.

Comment: Your `beauty()` function is being called multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to the perils of impure functions, i.e., side effects.

Answer (score 2):

When you are checking for if `beauty()` is equal to `text`, the function is being called. And you have multiple `if/elif` statements... So the unction is being called more than once. So I suggest calling the function once and storing that in a variable.

```
def beauty():
    print("Belle")
    return "Beast"

def gaston(butty):
    if butty == "Beast":
        print("No one’s as slick")
    elif butty == None:
        print("No one’s as quick")
    if butty == "Belle":
        print("What a guy")
    else:
        print("Belle")  

butty = beauty()
gaston(butty)
```

Comment: btw, don't make `butty` a global. You can just pass it as a parameter to `gaston()`.

Comment: @quamrana hehehehe... `butty`

Comment: already did... you just saw wrong :)